# Is there a difference between joshcooper-powershell and puppetlabs-powershell?

Tags: powershell, puppet

I tried to install puppetlabs-powershell v1.0.1 on my puppet master, but it complained that joshcooper-powershell v0.0.6 is already installed.

Are they the same? Compatible?
Which version is newer?

I have the opportunity to force the install using 'puppet module install --force'. Good or bad idea?

For reference, this is the command I used:

```
sudo puppet module install puppetlabs-powershell --version 1.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR use puppetlabs-powershell in favor of joshcooper-powershell.

The [git repository](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-powershell) for both modules is puppetlabs/puppetlabs-powershell.

Note that Josh is (now) a PuppetLabs employee and likely moved his module to the official supported ones. His [module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/joshcooper/powershell) has not seen a release since 2013, so it's safe to assume that it's been superseded by [PuppetLabs' module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/powershell).